# Is this a tupelo?

Tags: identification

The question says it all - alternate single entire leaves with smooth margins, and I tend to believe that the buds should be telling, but I'd like confirmation that it is indeed [Nyssa sylvatica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyssa_sylvatica):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Here's the proof that they are sassafras:

[image]

Comment: can you smell a broken twig and report back?

Comment: @ThatIdiot  snapped a pic of a bud and posted it as an edit. The taste... Extremely faint if there at all.

Comment: That tri-lobed leaf in the final picture confirms that it is sassafrass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tree is unquestionably Sassafras albidum.  The original poster should watch to photograph oncoming flowers from those swelling terminal buds as definitive proof for the Nyssa-sayers.

Sassafras will have sympodial branching; Nyssa will not.

Flowering and fruiting morphology on these dioecious species are remarkably different, and occur at much different times.

Bark matches old Sassafras.

Variable leaf morphology speaks for itself - VARIABLE.

I'm not aware that Nyssa will ever have notably green young twigs, and I just traversed and updated yesterday the Nyssa Grove planted here in Louisville in 3014, now comprising over 30 taxa.

Comment: This is the canonical answer. Trust me on this one! And thank you very much for your contribution! Best wishes!

Answer (score 3):

It looks more like a really nice *Sassafrass albidum* to me than a Tupelo (which on Long Island refers to *Nyssa sylvatica*)

The leaves look a bit fuzzy, or tomentose, whereas Nyssa leaves are shinier. The leaf veining in your photos seems a bit more like that of Sassafras. The colors are appropriate for either.

Sassafras typically have 3 different leaf shapes, and your photos show only one shape, but this could be due to the maturity of the tree.

The branching pattern looks more like Sassafras. Nyssa sylvatica branching tends to occur more at right angles.

The bark, though reminiscent of mature Tupelo in some situations, is also more like what is seen on old Sassafras.

[Missouri Botanical Garden](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=i820) has some photos that show Sassafras buds which look like the ones in your photo.

Comment: Hard to believe with all the leaves shown ,there is not one typical sassafrass lobed leaf. That would also be exceptionally large for sassafrass in zone 8. Also sassafrass twigs are green , giving it the American Indian name.

Comment: @blacksmith37 do you agree with Sassafras or think it Nyssa? The last three photos show green twigs.

Comment: Probably a sour gum.

Comment: You were so right! Thank you very much!